# Cannot resolve method 'equals(long)'

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm working on a spring boot application. However in my service impl class I'm getting a "Cannot resolve method 'equals(long)' when I try to use the equals() method. Any ideas on what the issue my be and how to fix it. Here is part of my service class:

```java
    @Override
    public CommentDto updateComment(Long postId, long commentId, CommentDto commentRequest) {
        // retrieve post entity by id
        Post post = postRepository.findById(postId).orElseThrow(
                () -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Post", "id", postId));

        // retrieve comment by id
        Comment comment = commentRepository.findById(commentId).orElseThrow(() ->
                new ResourceNotFoundException("Comment", "id", commentId));

        if(!comment.getPost().getId().equals(post.getId())){
            throw new BlogApiException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Comment does not belongs to post");
        }

        comment.setName(commentRequest.getName());
        comment.setEmail(commentRequest.getEmail());
        comment.setBody(commentRequest.getBody());

        Comment updatedComment = commentRepository.save(comment);
        return mapToDTO(updatedComment);
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of `comment.getPost().getId()`? Given that this sounds like a Java compilation error, I suspect you should be able to reproduce this in a [mcve] which doesn't refer to spring-boot at all.

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace please?

Comment: for checking equality of `long` (lowercase) use `==` -> `if (comment.getPost().getId() != (post.getId())`

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, the compilation error is on this line:

```
if (!comment.getPost().getId().equals(post.getId())) {
```

From the error message, we can infer that `post.getId()` returns `long`, and that the `comment.getPost().getId()` expression has a static (reference) type that doesn't provide an `equals(long)` or `equals(Long)` method.  (It most likely just has the `equals(Object)` inherited from `Object`.)

So ... assuming you are actually intending to do an integer equality test here ... there are a couple of ways to do this:

This one will work if the return type of `comment.getPost().getId()` is a subtype of `Number`

```
if (comment.getPost().getId().longValue() != post.getId())) {
```

This will only work if the return type is `Long`:

```
if (!comment.getPost().getId().equals(Long.valueOf(post.getId()))) {
```

You could also solve this by being consistent about the return types of your (at least two) `getId()` methods.  (Why does one return `long` and the other something reference type?  You are doing the same thing in the `updateComment` method signature.)

---

Note that this is NOT a solution:

```
if (comment.getPost().getId() != Long.valueOf(post.getId())) {
```

You should not use `==` to compare 2 values whose type are a wrapper class; i.e. `Boolean`, `Byte`, `Short`, `Character`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Float` or `Double`.  The `==` operator will compare references, and that *may* give the wrong answer ... if your intention is to compare numeric values.